# Using crispy in Django to change the field size

Tags: django, forms, bootstrap-4

I have a very simple form for my template. I would like to change its size.

[image]

How can you do this? by adding a widget in my forms.py file or by adding a certain class in my template?

My template:

```
              <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-0">
                    {{ basic_form.choices_product|as_crispy_field }}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger">Wyszukaj <i class="fas fa-heart fa-lg"></i></button>
              </form>
```

I was looking for information on the internet, but to no avail.

I use Bootstrap 4, Django 2+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your template is evaluated, the variable specified between your {{ ... }} will be replaced with an "input" element in the HTML DOM. You want to render this "input" element with the Bootstrap 4 class "form-control-lg" or a style attribute such as "line-height", which will change height of the element.

crispy-forms allows you to do all this from forms.py

Specifically, you can change the way form fields are rendered with crispy-forms by using the Layout class from the [crispy_forms.layout](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/blob/master/crispy_forms/layout.py) module. Full details are given [here](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/d-0/layouts.html) in the crispy-forms docs.

In your case, you would need to (1) Add a FormHelper to your form; (2) Add a layout to your helper; and (3) Use the Field layout object to set attributes on any field.

So you can change forms.py like so:

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Field

from django import forms

class BasicForm(forms.Form):
     [...] # Define your fields here
     def__init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            # Add a FormHelper
            self.helper = FormHelper()
            # Add a layout to your helper
            self.helper.layout = Layout(
                # Use the Field layout object to set attributes on 
                # choices_product field. type="text" should be there by
                # default if you have used a CharField or TextField.
                Field(
                    'choices_product', css_class="form-control form-control-lg", id="exampleInputSize3", placeholder=".form-control-lg",
                )
            )
        super(BasicForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you for youre answer. I traing do it but, but i still I have no effect. Haw it bean look for input like this <input class="form-control form-control-lg" id="exampleInputSize3" type="text" placeholder=".form-control-lg"> in my crispy form?

Comment: To get that set of attributes in your input element, you can use the Field layout object from crispy_forms.layout, as mentioned in my first response. I've edited the response to show how you would get those specific attributes in your input element.